# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I have this code where I try to set the score.

```
var score = 0;
chrome.storage.sync.set({"playerScore": score});
```

I have storage enabled in my manifest.json file, so that's not it. Sorry if the solution is obvious, I'm still relatively new to using this.

Manifest file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Red Dot",
"description": "This extension is a quick little game I made. It is worthless, 
but it should provide you with at least 5 seconds of entertainment.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

The script is entitled "script.js" and is used in the "popup.html" file.

Comment: 1) What file is this code in? 2) Can you add your manifest file to the question?

Comment: None of the 23,000+ existing questions and answers here were able to help you figure this out? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+read+property+of+undefined

Comment: I could only find a few that were specifically looking at the chrome.storage API, and the one I did find the guy forgot to add storage to his manifest. I hate asking questions on here, but I've spent three days on this and have found no answer.

Comment: Are you setting a breakpoint in devtools debugger? Make sure to do it after any access to `chrome` API, otherwise you're hitting https://crbug.com/754976

Comment: My guess is that you're either not having the right path to your script inside popup.html or you're the victim of a Content Security Policy error. Also, as a debugging step, add something like `if(chrome.storage == null || chrome.storage == 'undefined'){console.log('storage doesn't exist')}`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help offered. It has suddenly decided to start working, I have no idea why. Thanks for the suggestion to implement the debugging conditional, as stated before I am new to this, so that'll be helpful.

Comment: @SimonHyll hi there i know its an old thread, but I'm having the same problem and when i tried your debugging code , it show 'storage doesnt exist', any idea why? and how to solve tis problem? Thank'

Comment: @dmh I havent worked with extensions for a while so cant say off the top of my head, sorry. But I would recommend starting a new project and following a tutorial word for word letter by letter until you have a functioning project. Then you compare that project to your original project and punch yourself for having made the unforgivable mistake of adding a period or a slash somewhere where it wasnt supposed to be. Good luck!